# Cannot mmap after switching to 64 bit mode in a Linux user-space process that started as 32-bit

Tags: linux, x86, x86-64, system-calls, 32bit-64bit

I tried to do an `mmap` syscall after switching to 64 bit mode on x86 Linux (Linux version 5.15.6), but the syscall returns `ENOMEM`. A minimal reproducible example is given by the following assembly code:

```
.text
.global _start

_start:
.code32

jmp $0x33, $start64 // jmp to start64 and change mode to 64 bit

.code64
start64:

mov $9, %rax // mmap
mov $0, %rdi // NULL
mov $0x1000, %rsi // size
mov $1, %rdx // PROT_READ
mov $0x22, %r10
mov $0, %r8
mov $0, %r9
syscall

mov $60, %rax // 64 bit style exit
mov $0, %rdi
syscall
```

The corresponding output of `strace` is:

```
execve("./mmap_test32", ["./mmap_test32"], 0x7ffe0ccd7920 /* 60 vars */) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, 0, 0) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
exit(0)                                 = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Does anyone have an idea why this is not working?

Comment: Related (but not duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24113729/switch-from-32bit-mode-to-64-bit-long-mode-on-64bit-linux ... this is very poorly supported, and I can't be sure that either the kernel or strace is actually doing anything sensible.

Comment: What we know for sure is that the syscall returns `-1`, so it is pretty certain that it fails. Other syscalls (like `open`) do work properly. I am aware that this mode is poorly supported, but it would be interesting to know what the reasons are and if there is any possible fix to it.

Comment: wild speculation: does `MAP_32BIT` help? I'm imagining what might happen if it generates a random unused 64-bit address then tries to add it to a 32-bit VM ...

Comment: Indeed, when adding the `MAP_32BIT` flag the `mmap` does work correctly. Thanks!
However, it would be nice to be able to either increase the size of the virtual memory or prevent `mmap` from generating too big addresses.

The reason is that we would like to execute unaltered, foreign code afterwards.

Comment: IDK if it's possible to reset what kind of process Linux things this is.  Possibly with a `personality(2)` system call?  If that can unset `ADDR_LIMIT_32BIT`?  Maybe with `personality(PER_LINUX)` instead of `PER_LINUX_32BIT` which is probably what execve on a 32-bit ELF implies.  Obviously it would be easier if you could just make this a 64-bit process in the first place, or execve a 64-bit ELF instead of doing major hacks like hard-coding the kernel's 64-bit user-CS segment selector constant and changing modes in user-space.

Comment: The personality of the process is `PER_LINUX|READ_IMPLIES_EXEC`,
setting this to `PER_LINUX` doesn't change anything.

Generally, it doesn't seem like setting the personality has an effect on the running process, for example after setting `ADDR_NO_RANDOMIZE` in a normal 64 process doesn't prevent the resulting address of an mmap to be random, but using `setarch -R ./test` (which does a personality syscall and then execve) does.

Comment: I also didn't see `ADDR_LIMIT_32BIT` (set with `setarch  -B ./test`) having any effect, neither for our 32 bit to 64 bit switch process nor for a regular 64 bit process, which is a bit odd.

I also had a look at at the modify_ldt syscall, but this also doesn't seem to help, so i will treat this experiment as failed.